# Failed to transform firebase-auth-22.2.0.aar

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error.

> Failed to transform firebase-auth-22.2.0.aar
> (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.2.0) to match attributes
> {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE,
> dexing-enable-desugaring=true,
> dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true,
> dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.category=library,
> org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release,
> org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

I tried to update kotlin, build gradle, all libraries, flutter clean, invalidate cache... nothing work.

Here is my configuration

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 34

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0')
```

What else I can do ?

Comment: what is your minsdk ?

Comment: minSdkVersion 21

Comment: Resolved with minSdkVersion 24. Thank you @Anand

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Resolved with minSdkVersion 24. Thank you @Anand

Comment: LOL, thanks, I was about to hit the Post your question regarding this issue: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H

Thanks!

Comment: Well, this isn't really a solution, is it? It removes the error but now the minSDKVersion is a lot higher than before. Yet, so far it is the only solution I found.

Comment: Enabling minify in the debug buildTypes is the correct answer since this problem only occurs when running the app locally (debugging). Build works fine with minSdkVersion 21.

Answer (score 5):

`minSdkVersion 24` didn't work for me. I solved it with below, don't know why, through.

```
        debug {
            // fix Failed to transform firebase-auth-22.3.1.aar
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. This error only occurs when running the app locally (debugging) and builds flawlessly with minSdkVersion 21.