# Flutter -Android unable to build (Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar)

Tags: flutter

I started having these issues when I upgraded my kotin_version inside my build.gradle inside the project directory

```
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.10) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/zionnite/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/131ce0572a85fdeb525a81595856d4eb/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37m 51s
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to transform firebase-auth-22.2.0.aar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77416448/failed-to-transform-firebase-auth-22-2-0-aar)